# Ansible management of frequently off machines

Tags: linux, ansible

I'd like to use Ansible to manage configuration on about a dozen Linux workstations.  The problem is that, being physical machines that people use, they're frequently off.  So I need a solution for ensuring that, as I change the centralized configuration, it gets not only pushed out to machines that are up, but that it eventually gets pushed machines that come up weeks from now.

The idea I've had, and I'm open to better, is to have a cron job run @reboot to SSH into the server and request the playbook run against itself.

That seems to mean I need to:

- Create a *deploy* user on the server (deploy@server)
- Create a *deploy* user on each workstation (deploy@ws) and give them sudo powers.
- Add the public key for deploy@server to the authorized_keys of deploy@ws
- Generate a new SSH key for deploy@ws, and add that newly generated SSH key to the authorized_keys of deploy@server
- Set up a workstation cron job to run as deploy@ws to SSH into the server and run ansible-playbook with a --limit of the workstation in question.  That job runs as deploy@server, who then SSHs back in as deploy@ws to actually do the configuration.

That feels more than a little convoluted.  Is there some more straightforward solution for this that I'm missing?

Comment: Hi @Rgaddi  - this seems like a question for devops.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MrR, there's a devops.stackexchange.com?  You're definitely correct that's a better target for this question; it just feels like every time I look SE has forked off another sub-sub-category to its own part of the world.

Comment: Hi @Rgaddi - yep - https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proxying to a central server and back is not needed. Install Python and Ansible on managed nodes and run plays on the local host. This changes Ansible from a push to a pull.

[ansible-pull](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-pull.html) is the most well known example of such a script. It assumes plays can be retrieved from a source control repository. Not the most elegant thing, but certainly a useful example of scripting ansible-playbook with ad-hoc inventory. Namely, it by default limits the host pattern to  `localhost` plus `socket.getfqdn()` so you can provide the full inventory but it only runs for itself.

An advantage of such a pull model is possibly removing the need for privilaged remote users, if the script is run as root in a scheduled task.

Disadvantage, this is much easier to run on hosts that can run Ansible, so POSIX operating systems, not Windows or network gear. Tracking inventory doesn't get easier in a pull model, consider implementing some kind of reporting by turning on callback plugins.

Comment: What do you consider inelegant about ansible-pull?

Comment: ansible-pull requires a source control check out via one of a few supported Ansible modules. Great if you use one of those VCSes, but not the only way to do it.  ansible-playbook also isn't intended to be run non-interactively, but pull does so.  To its credit, pull is quite polished and practical.

Comment: My concerns with using ansible-pull instead of doing it with push-style were that it seemed to complicate a) centralized reporting of who's had what update and b) role-based deployment, since everyone just thinks they're localhost.  Or I'm just understanding it wrong.

Comment: There is not reporting of who's had what in push ansible either, would want reporting callbacks (ARA,  AWX/Tower, notification plugins).  ansible-pull inventory includes the OS's hostname, so  you can use push inventory is if this matches. Effectively similar to  `ansible-playbook --limit localhost,$(hostname) --connection local`

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at [`ansible-pull`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-pull.html). I feel like you're about to try to recreate it.